# If I call Spinner.performClick(); in onStart() spinner doesn't open

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want that in the `Activity` `onStart()` spinner opens automatically, so I can show the choices to the user, but unfortunately when I call `mySpinner.performClick();` in `onStart()`

It doesn't open at all.

Why happens this? How could I make the spinner opening in `onStart()`?

Comment: I think you should do this in `onCreate()`

Comment: @grrigore why exactly?

Comment: That was just my opinion, do you get an error? Can you post some code?

Comment: @grrigore I have tried and in onCreate() It even worse and makes app crashing.

Comment: Posting code is useless since Spinner is just a standard spinner without any customization and there is nothing relevant that could be related to this error. In onCreate the spinner is just initialized and If I don't call  mySpinner.performClick(); everything works as supposed and I'm able to use the spinner and its element selection listener.

Comment: What happens if you call performClick()?

Comment: @grrigore As I have said the spinner doesn't open. I have used `performClick()` to make It opening so that users haven't to click It manually to open It and see the choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do like this and spinner show. You even can call it in `onCreate()`.

```
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
            spinner.performClick();
      }
});
```

I think `spinner.performClick()` only work well after the activity finish laid out because I receive error

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null for displayid = 0 is not valid; is your activity running?

when I call `spinner.performClick()` inside `onCreate` (or `onStart`) without `post` or waiting

Comment: this makes the spinner opening but for some reason also the onSelectedItem() listener is triggered despite user hasn't selected anything.